# Python monitoring radiusd service. Loadbalancer tcp healthcheck

Tags: python, apache, google-cloud-platform, freeradius, radius

I have a curious situation.

I'm working on a pair of `freeradius` servers and had planned to stick a load balancer in front of them in GCP. Not entirely sure if this is the best approach, as I don't have much experience with Freeradius really.. but it's the avenue I went down.

So I threw together some Terraform to build a couple of GCP instances and wrote a startup script to deploy the application and configuration files. All good so far.

Then I got started on the load balancer, and I noticed that GCP offer a `UDP` Load Balancer as a service, great.. that works. However, it really wants a health check. Which is in principle fine, but not really possible over `UDP`.

So then, I thought... maybe I'll write some python which can check if the `radiusd` service is up and running, and if not.. stop `httpd`... That way the load balancer can run it's `http healthcheck` and if the `radiusd` service stops, the python script will simply stop the `httpd service`, and the load balancer will know that server is down, and switch to the other one.

My questions are multi-fold.. Although this approach may work, is it the best approach? To me it seems the more I drive down this road, the more it feels like the wrong way.

If by chance, it does seem to be the best approach.. I don't have much experience of running python output to a webpage. I've written a simple bit of python to check the service, as such?

```
import os
import subprocess

def running(name):
    with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as hide_output:
        exit_code = subprocess.Popen(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=hide_output, stderr=hide_output).wait()
        return exit_code == 0

if not running('radiusd'):
    os.system('service httpd stop')
```

As you can see, in this instance it will stop the `httpd` service.. which will achieve what I want.. but it won't then start `httpd` when the `radiusd` service comes back up.

So, is there an alternative solution?

If not, is there a way I can run the script as a web app, which constantly runs checking the `radiusd` service and bringing a holding page up or down depending on the outcome?

Thanks, and sorry for the essay.

Comment: You can run healthchecks over UDP.  You rely on the fact that the host sends an ICMP message back to the LB if the port isn't open

Comment: Hi Arran, Apologies I should have mentioned. The issue is that GCP Loadbalancer seem to only allow the healthcheck over HTTP. I'm unable to configure a healthcheck for UDP.

Comment: Any update on this? We are stuck on a similar situation.