# Python: Logic in not starting a service if it's running

Tags: python, subprocess

This is kind of related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539764/python-monitoring-radiusd-service-loadbalancer-tcp-healthcheck?noredirect=1#comment95891906_54539764) but I've put it into it's own question as I feel that it's a valid question in it's own right.

I have the following python which will stop the `httpd` service if the `radiusd` service fails. The reason behind this is detail

```
import os
import subprocess
import time


def running(name):
    with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as hide_output:
        exit_code = subprocess.Popen(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=hide_output, stderr=hide_output).wait()
        return exit_code == 0

while True:
    if not running('radiusd'):
        os.system('service httpd stop')

    if running('radiusd'):
        os.system('service httpd start')

    time.sleep(10)
```

Firstly, I'm running this in a forever loop and had planned to run it on startup in `.bashrc` or something. So that every 10 seconds it will run. This is conceptually fine, but is there a better way to have it poll every few seconds, without using a cron job?

Secondly, I don't like how it tries to start the service even though it's running. In the current form, it simply runs `service httpd start` every 10 seconds if everything is fine. This seems taxing on the system and a bit of a waste of everyones time/energy. There must be a way for it to only try starting the process if it's not already running.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if just helps to write down the issues you're facing. As I was typing the above I realised an easy way to achieve it would be to just add opposite apposing conditionals as such:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time


def running(name):
    with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as hide_output:
        exit_code = subprocess.Popen(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=hide_output, stderr=hide_output).wait()
        return exit_code == 0

while True:
    if not running('radiusd'):
        if running('httpd'):
            os.system('service httpd stop')

    if running('radiusd'):
        if not running('httpd'):
            os.system('service httpd start')

    time.sleep(10)
```